# Is there a way to nest a iterator in a for loop

Tags: python, loops

so I have an iterator set with some options on it, I want to nest it in a simple while or for-loop but it seems that it's not permitted, here is my code. Thank you for any help in advance.

```py
def gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters):
    m = len(y)
    J_History = np.zeros(num_iters)
    theta_history = np.array([0, 0] * num_iters).reshape(2, num_iters)
    J_History[0] = computeCost(X, y, theta)

while 0 < num_iters:                                    <-- I need a outer loop for the iterator to be repeated "x" times
    with np.nditer(X, order='C', flags=['external_loop'], op_flags=['readwrite']) as it:
        for x in it:
            theta[0] = theta[0] - (alpha * (x[0] * theta[0] + x[1] * theta[1] - x[2]))/m
            theta[1] = theta[1] - ((alpha * (x[0] * theta[0] + x[1] * theta[1] - x[2]))*x[1])/m

J_History[iter] = computeCost(X, y, theta)
```

Comment: `for i in range(num_iters)`. Your "loop" never changes the loop index (always comparing 0).

Comment: What's the `it` in the inner `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands, `num_iters` doesn't change in the `while` loop.

You could use a `for` loop:

```
for _ in range(num_iters):
    with np.nditer(X, order='C', flags=['external_loop'], op_flags=['readwrite']) as it:
        for x in it:
            theta[0] = theta[0] - (alpha * (x[0] * theta[0] + x[1] * theta[1] - x[2]))/m
            theta[1] = theta[1] - ((alpha * (x[0] * theta[0] + x[1] * theta[1] - x[2]))*x[1])/m
```

You could use a `while` loop instead, but would need to increment the counter yourself.